# How to use piecewise in Octave

Tags: octave

Is there an intuitive way of using the [piecewise function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) in Octave?

May you kindly provide a simple example for the absolute value function?

```
y=x if x>=0    
y=-x if x<0
```

Comment: See [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533221/piecewise-function-plot-in-matlab/533741) on Math.StackExchange. Or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868010/how-to-define-a-piecewise-function-in-matlab).

Comment: This belongs on Stackexchange, but you can do `y = x.*(x>=0) + (-x).*(x<0)` .

Comment: @Christian Clason, can you reply here so that I can tag this answer as the chosen one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you just write your own piecewise function? Something like:

```
function [y] = my_piecewise(x)
    y = x
    if x< 0
       y = -x
    endif
end function
```

Comment: anyway I need to write a specific function. There is no piecewise function like in mathematica